# filter duplicates from a data frame in r

Tags: r, duplicates, dplyr, unique

I have a dataframe with one observation per row and two observations per subject. I'd like to filter out just the rows with duplicate 'day' numbers.

```
ex <- data.frame('id'= rep(1:5,2), 'day'= c(1:5, 1:3,5:6))
```

The following code filters out just the second duplicated row, but not the first. Again, I'd like to filter out both of the duplicated rows.

```
ex %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    filter(duplicated(day))
```

The following code works, but seems clunky. Does anyone have a more efficient solution?

```
ex %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    filter(duplicated(day, fromLast = TRUE) | duplicated(day, fromLast = FALSE))
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`duplicated` can be applied on the whole dataset and this can be done with just `base R` methods.

```
ex[duplicated(ex)|duplicated(ex, fromLast = TRUE),]
```

---

Using `dplyr`, we can `group_by` both the columns and `filter` only when the number of rows (`n()`) is greater than 1.

```
ex %>% 
     group_by(id, day) %>%
     filter(n()>1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Single tidyverse pipe:

```
exSinglesOnly <- 
    ex %>% 
    group_by(id,day) %>% # the complete group of interest
    mutate(duplicate = n()) %>% # count number in each group
    filter(duplicate == 1) %>% # select only unique records
    select(-duplicate) # remove group count column
```

> ```
> > exSinglesOnly
> Source: local data frame [4 x 2]
> Groups: id, day [4]
>
>      id   day
>   <int> <int>
> 1     4     4
> 2     5     5
> 3     4     5
> 4     5     6
> ```

Comment: Oh, I hadn't seen @Akrun's second answer. This is a duplicate of that then, but I will leave it up to help explain the logic involved with the complete grouping and subsequent filtration.